# How to display FieldSet for an sObject List in PageBlockSection?

Tags: visualforce, fieldsets

I have seen examples where people display fieldset for an sobject.

But instead of mySobject if i want to display the field set for a list of sobjects?

Comment: for example:
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.properNames}" var="f"> 
        <apex:outputText value="{!Contact[f]}" /><br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>

Comment: Is it a list of SObjects of the same type or of different SObject types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean by a list of SObjects of the same SObject type, say Contact. And then the code can be pretty easy.

**page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="fieldSetExtension"> 
    <apex:repeat value="{!contactList}" var="c">
        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.Name_Set}" var="f"> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!c[f]}" />
            <br/> 
        </apex:repeat> 
        <br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class fieldSetExtension 
{
    public List<Contact> contactList {get; set;}
    public fieldSetExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        contactList = [Select Id, Name, LastName, Email, MobilePhone, Level__c From Contact];
    }
}
```

Of course, you should be using Dynamic SOQL here, which I am too lazy to implement here. But the concept is the same.